# Catch failed recipients in Symfony/Mailer 6.x?

Tags: symfony-mailer

In want replace deprecated SwiftMailer v6.3.0 with new [Symfony/Mailer v6.x](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html). In old SwiftMailer I collect [failed recipients](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html#getting-failures-by-reference) so that I know who has not received mail.

```
$successfulRecipients = $mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
```

Symfony/Mailer is not working this way. How do I find failed recipients in Symfony/Mailer? Maybe with try/catch for [TransportExceptionInterface](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#handling-sending-failures) but there is no example what exactly is returned.

How do I get the mail addresses which have not received the mail? Because maybe their mailbox was full or the mail was too big?

Comment: Do you have manage to catch the failed recipients?

Answer (score 1):

When symfony successfully hands a mail over to the transport server (e.g. SMTP) it is concidered done for symfony.

As you wrote you may can fetch issues with the transport server by using [TransportExceptionInterface](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#debugging-emails). This is done by simple try/catch

```php
    use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;
    
    $email = new Email();
    try {
        $mailer->send($email);
    } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
        echo $e->getDebug();
        // error message or try to resend the message

    }
```